# combinatorial or permutation, which one is right in this case?

Tags: combinatorics

I have this problem. Suppose that for building a hotel, the architect can choose to build R different types of rooms (eg. double, single, etc), with a particular size S, painted with a certain color C, and it can hold a type of bed B. How many possible combinations are considering the number of rooms, colors, shapes and beds? It can occur repetition of the values.

Possible solution:

C^R represents the probable combinations of number of rooms and colours

S^R combinations of sizes and number of rooms, so we will have

(C^R+S^R), would that be fine?

now the problem is also how I can consider the other data of the number of probable bed types B, should it be like:

B^(C^R+S^R) ?

Thanks

Comment: To me it looks like simple $R*C*B$ but maybe I am misreading it.  It looks like the room is just painted with one color out of $C$ choices.

Comment: @turkeyhundt in the case that I have 3 rooms and 3 available colours, they can be painted in 8 different colours, but I have also 3 different types of rooms, eg. single, double, suite. So I think we will end up with 3.8=24 possible combinations. Is it like that?

Comment: @Lila: Why $8$ colors? You have a choice of $3$ colors for each room, so if you have $n$ rooms, you can color them in $3^n$ ways. For $n=3$ that’s $27$, not $8$. If, on the other hand, you don’t know the number of rooms, but you have $n$ **types** of rooms and want to know how many different combinations of type and color are possible for a single room, the answer is $3n$.

Comment: thank you very much @BrianM.Scott, I have added another value and make a draft solution of it; could you help me out?

Comment: This question is **incomprehensible**, and adding a bounty cannot help summoning usable answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single room, you have $BC$ ways to paint it and put a bed in it.  When you say $R$ types of room, the temptation is to say you choose one type of room, paint it and put a bed in it, giving $RBC$ ways to make one room.  It looks like you are thinking about a collecton of rooms, maybe with a maximum total area, but you have not specified the question well enough to deal with that.  If there were a fixed number of rooms, $N$, and the order of the rooms matters, there would be $(RBD)^N$ ways to choose the rooms.  Please *think* about your question more clearly.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was thinking about a collection of rooms and the sizes that could be build are fixed also: 100 sm, 200 sm and 400 sm; so according to your answer and if I take the probable area sizes I would end up with: (RBCS)^N

Comment: That is true if order matters, so having the first room blue and the second red is different from the first red and second blue.